# Java lottery game : finding a sequence in an array

Tags: java

How do I see if the first 2, 3, 4 or all numbers are part of another array?Here "lottery" generates 10 numbers 1-100 and "numbers" is getting user's input 5 times.The program compares user's 5 numbers to numbers 1-5 of lottery , 2-6 and so on.Im trying to see if the user guessed a sequence in the lottery array but I cant get it to print out "You guessed 2 nrs" if the user guessed 2 ,3 ,4 or all numbers one after another.I incremented a counter and also tried switch statements but doesn't work.

```
// to check if user guessed a sequence
int counter=0;
        
for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length - 5; i++) {  // 1-5
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (lottery[i] == numbers[j]) {
            counter++;
        }           
    }
}
            
for (int i = 1; i < lottery.length - 4 ; i++) { // 2-6
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (lottery[i] == numbers[j]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
            
for (int i = 2; i < lottery.length - 3 ; i++) { // 3 -7 numbers of lottery array
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (lottery[i] == numbers[j]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 3; i < lottery.length - 2; i++) { // 4 - 8  numbers of lottery array
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (lottery[i] == numbers[j]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 4; i < lottery.length - 1; i++) {   // 5 -9  numbers of lottery array
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (lottery[i] == numbers[j]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 5; i < lottery.length ; i++) { // 6 -10  numbers of lottery array
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (lottery[i] == numbers[j]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length && i < 2; i++) {      // 2 sequence
     counter = numbers[i];
}
        
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length && i < 3; i++) {      // 3 sequence
     counter= numbers[i];
}

for (int i =0; i < numbers.length && i < 4; i++) {       // 4 sequence
     counter = numbers[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {                // 5 sequence
     counter = numbers[i];
}
            
switch (counter) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("You guessed one sequence");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("You guessed two sequences");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("You guessed three sequences");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("You guessed four sequences");
        break;
}
```

Comment: If there is anything I can improve on the answer I have provided, please let me know, un-accepting doesn't give me feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit confusing, most likely because you are not using functions, for what you want to achieve there is a nice code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-an-array-is-subarray-of-another-array/), lets take a look at it:

```
static boolean isSubArray(int A[], int B[], int n, int m) 
{ 
    // Two pointers to traverse the arrays 
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
  
    // Traverse both arrays simultaneously 
    while (i < n && j < m) 
    { 
        // If element matches 
        // increment both pointers 
        if (A[i] == B[j]) 
        { 
            i++; 
            j++; 
            // If array B is completely 
            // traversed 
            if (j == m) 
                return true; 
        } 
          
        // If not, 
        // increment i and reset j 
        else
        { 
            i = i - j + 1; 
            j = 0; 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Now you have a function that will return true if whole sequence A is in sequence B, but that is not the whole code you seem to want. You need to split guessed sequence, what if there is subsequence that fits?

Example (how many are guessed in following?):

```
int lottery[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; //here we got full match
int B[] = {1,2,4,5,6}; //last three make it 3
int C[] = {1,2,3,7,9}; //first three make it 3
int D[] = {1,3,4,5,9}; //and here is it in the middle!
```

So what now? You need to check for each lengths, higher lengths first of course, a simple solution can be as follows (check [how to create a subarray](https://www.techiedelight.com/get-subarray-array-specified-indexes-java/)):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static<T> T[] subArray(T[] array, int beg, int end) {
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, beg, end + 1);
}

public static boolean checkAll(int A[], int B[], int n, int m, int subset){
  for(int i=0;i+subset<n;i++){ //i+subset must be within range
    //checking the current subset, iterate them all
    if(isSubArray(subArray(A,i,i+subset), B, n, m)){
      return true; //if it is there return true!
    }
  }
  return false; //no luck!
}

int lottery[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int D[] = {1,3,4,5,9}; 
counter = 0;
for(counter=D.length; counter>0; counter--){
    if(checkAll(D, lottery, D.length, lottery.length, counter)){
      break; //we found match, can end
    }
}
System.out.println("You guessed sequence of length: %d ", counter);
```

I guess I have a little bit misunderstood what you are trying to achieve, so same approach for sequences of the lottery:

```
//subset is probably 5 for lottery
public static int checkAll(int A[], int B[], int n, int m, int subset_A , int subset_B){
  int total = 0;//we return this 
  for(int i=0;i+subset_B<m;i++){ //each subset in lottery
   for(int j=0;j+subset_A<n;j++){ //each subset in guesses
    if(isSubArray(subArray(A,j,j+subset),subArray(B,i,i+subset), n, m)){
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}
int occurences = 0;
for(int counter=lottery.length; counter>0; counter--){
      occurences+=checkAll(D, lottery, D.length, lottery.length, counter, 5);
}
System.out.println("Your guessed sequence (and its parts) was present %d times", occurences );
```

I am still not sure what exactly you want to do, so this code might be a little bit overkill. The code was not tested, some syntax errors might come in the way.